# How can I start Delphi application with the hidden main form?

Tags: delphi

I have the application on Delphi with the following main form initialization:

```
Application.CreateForm(<class>, <variable>);
```

It shows the main form when the application starts.

How can I start Delphi application with the hidden main form (or on non-visual mode at all)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In project source file set:

```
Application.ShowMainForm := false;
```

just before main form creation:

```
Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
```

Update from Remy:

You can also set it in the MainForm's `OnCreate` event. The requirement is to set `ShowMainForm` before `Application.Run()` is called.

Update from gabr:
Main form must also have Visible property set to False

Comment: You can also set it in the MainForm's `OnCreate` event.  The requirement is to set `ShowMainForm` before `Application.Run()` is called.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the taskbar icon visible? I have a login form which only makes the main form visible once login succeeds, but then there's no taskbar icon (or alt-tab thumbnail). Sorry for wanting my cake and eating it :)

Comment: @DaveBoltman Instead of hiding the form just set the forms WindowState to wsMinimized.

Comment: Main form must also have `Visible` property set to `False`.