# Delphi Form Creation and Showing

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-xe6

I am trying to create an application with 2 forms in Delphi XE6. Depending on a `ParamStr` setting Form2 may or may not be shown before Form1.

In a quick test app both forms are created before `Form1.Show` is invoked - during which Form2 is shown or not

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ParamStr(1) = 'foo' then
      Form2.FooShow;
end;

procedure TForm2.FooShow;
begin
   ShowModal;
end;
```

*However* in the "real" application I am seeing a different behaviour.

In this case `Form1.Show` is being called as soon as `Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1)` is called. This is *before* Form2 is being created, which is causing problems as Form2 doesn't exist when it is needed.

Any explanation why the behaviour would differ? Am I missing a setting buried somewhere in *Project>Options*

Comment: I've recreated the application using fresh Forms and it's now behaving as expected - there certainly seems to be a setting that's snuck into the original somewhere

Comment: As I pointed out in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24488482/224704): the setting that "snuck in" is the `Visible` property on `Form1`. I doubt you wrote additional code to explicitly show the form when created, otherwise you would have solved you problem far more easily. This leaves the only thing that will cause a form to be shown as soon as it's created is if the property `Visible = True` at design time.

Comment: Visible is set to true in the "working" version of the application.

Comment: You claim: "_Visible is set to true in the "working" version of the application_." To put it bluntly that's **absolute rubbish**! Unless there is something very significant you neglected to mention about your "working" quick test, going to `Form1` and setting `Visible=True` in the _design-time property editor_ **will cause an access violation** when `TForm1.FormShow` attempts to show `Form2`. I can only assume you mistakenly think Visible was true because `Form1` was automatically shown when you ran the app. **REMINDER**: The main form is always shown automatically, even if Visible is false.

Comment: Dan, seriously try following **your own instructions** in your question, **AND** set Visible=True in `Form1`'s ***property editor at design time***. You will observe that: **(1)** `Form1` is shown as soon as it's created. **(2)** I.e. Before `Form2` is created. **(3)** And this will cause an access violation if `TForm1.FormShow` attempts to show `Form2`.

Comment: Craig - you're right - and apologies - Visible is set to True in the "broken" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If your form is persisted with `Visible` set to True, then it will be shown as soon as it's created.

Setting the property to False should resolve your problem.

**EDIT**

PS: Just in case someone with a similar problem has their main form unexpectedly show even though `Visible` is set to `False`. This happens because by default the application will show the main form regardless of its `Visible` property in the call to `Application.Run`.
If so, the following question should help: [How can I start Delphi application with the hidden main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24441787/224704)

**EDIT2**

For the sake of completeness, there are a couple other things that could cause a form to be shown as soon as it's created. However, these probably aren't applicable to this specific question.

- Any code that explicitly shows the form when it's created (such as the `OnCreate` event) would obviously cause the form to be shown. However, one would hope that such actions don't lead to these kinds of questions.
- An MDI child form can never be hidden. At best it can be minimised.

---

**TIP**

The quickest way to finding the answer to such questions is usually just a little bit of debugging.

- Set a break-point in your `FormShow` method.
- Go to Compiler Settings, and enable the option to build with debug DCU's. (You'll want to see the VCL code.)
- Rebuild and run your application.
- When you get to your break-point, open the Call Stack debug window.
- Navigate the call-stack looking for the trigger.

In this case you should have found the following code in `Forms.pas`.

```
procedure TCustomForm.DoCreate;
begin
  //...
  if fsVisible in FFormState then Visible := True; //<-- The trigger
end;
```

And a little more investagation on `fsVisible` would reveal the root cause as: The `Visible` property is set to `True`.

---

That said, you don't want to be coding this way because you're creating dependencies via globals. This is error-prone; and your little experiment shows shows just one of many subtle things that can cause problems.

Rather avoid the globals with something like the following changes in your DPR:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  ShowForms;
end;
```

Where `ShowForms` is implemented as:

```
procedure ShowForms;
var
  LForm1: TForm1;
  LForm2: TForm2;
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TFrom1, LForm1);
  Application.CreateForm(TFrom2, LForm2);

  if (ParamStr(1) = 'foo') then
    LForm2.Show
  else
   LForm1.Show;
end;
```

If you don't have any dependencies between the forms, the above will suffice.
If you do have a dependency, e.g. Form2 uses Form1: then you can explicitly pass a reference after creating the forms, bu before you start doing anything with them.

```
//Define a property on TForm2 E.g.
property MainForm: TForm1 read FMainForm write SetMainForm;

//Immediately after creating both forms tell form2 which to use as its main form.
LForm2.MainForm := LForm1;
```

Comment: Thanks Craig.  This is a secondary Form that is set to Showmodal during the OnShow of the Main Form, but is normally `Visible = False`

Comment: @DanKelly Your comment makes me wonder whether you understood my answer? You asked why your production `Form1` would be shown as soon as it is created. ***It will be if it is set to `Visible = True` at deisgn time***. The only time I referred to your secondary form was in the second part of my answer to suggest a less error-prone way of determining whether to show Form2. I.e. one that won't trigger an AV even if `Form1` is shown as soon as it's created.

Comment: In the "working" version of the application Form1 only shows (and I expect this) **after** Form2 (showing Modally) has been dismissed.